# AMPL continuous variable in index expression

Tags: cplex, ampl

I'm solving a small problem in AMPL and I faced a small problem. I have 4 sets **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D dimen 3** and 1 variable **x{A,B} binary** and **y{B,C} binary**.

Elements of subsets of **D** are all from **A**.

Each element of **A** MUST be assigned an element from **B**. **[this part is done]**

Every element from the assigned values of **B** MUST be assigned an element from **C**. **[Here is the problem]**

For this reason, I had to define a new variable **map{A}**, which maps elements from **A** to **B** (this means if x[a,b] = 1 then map[a] = b).

I want to write something like this: `y[ map[a],c]` where {a in A, c in C} which means the mapped b in **B** of a in **A** but cplex gives me the error **`"continuous variable in index expression"`**.

Is there anyway to do so? Thanks in advance. Your help is appreciated.

**Further Explanation:**

assume the following code:

```
set A;
set B;
set C;
set D dimen 3; #elements are from A

var x{A,B} binary;
var y{B,C} binary;
var map{A};

forall{a in A} sum {b in B} x[a,b] = 1; #every element from A must have a mapping to B
forall{b in B} sum {c in C} y[b,c] <= 1; #for each element from B, there can be max of 1 mapping to C

subject to mapAtoB{a in A, b in B}: x[a,b] = 1 ==> map[a] = b;
subject to constr{ (i,j,k) in D, c in C }: y[ map[i],c ] + y[ map[j],c ] + y[ map[k],c] = 2; #here is the problem .. I want to be able to say map[i] which is supposed to be equal to some element in B which was assigned to A

data;
set A:= 1 2 3 4;
set B:= a b c;
set C:= i ii iii;
set D: 1 2 3:= (1,2,3) (1,2,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to index a variable with a variable.  This is more the style of [constraint programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constraint-programming).  You can do what you are trying in AMPL and cplex by adding variables that indicate if an element of B was assigned an element of A.

```
var active{B} binary;
forall {A in A} sum {b in B} x[a,b] = 1
forall {b in B, a in A} x[a,b] <= active[b]
forall {b in B} sum {c in C} y[b,c] = active[b]
```

So if no element of A is assigned to `b`, then `b` doesn't get
assigned to an element of C.

Comment: thank you sir for the fast reply but I don't think this will work. I edited the question, can you check it please? Thanks

Comment: Because sir, as I stated in my question, I want to address "b" of an "a" using subsets of "D" `subject to constr{ (i,j,k) in D, c in C }: y[ map[i],c ] + y[ map[j],c ] + y[ map[k],c] = 2;` in your way, I can't perform this "addition" since I don't know what "b" was assigned to an "a". Your way will show which "b" was used but not to whom it was assigned. Thank you

Comment: In your question, you don't say anything about 'D' other than elements of subsets of D are all from A.  The specific question you asked was 'Every element from the assigned values of B MUST be assigned an element from C. [Here is the problem]'.  The answer I gave solves that problem.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad. What you suggested, I already did. Do you have an answer for my edits?